# How do you remove the default hypertext color when reloading a page using a CSS transition?

Tags: css

I was making a transition for these navigation buttons that makes the padding 5px more with a shadow, it works. However, whenever the page gets reloaded the text is blue for .5 seconds ([text when reloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUYPE.png)) which happens to be the same time it takes for the buttons to get its padding and shadow. Is there a way I can make the text remain white ([text .5 seconds after a reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAEFc.png)) when reloading?

Comment: I assume the button has some kind of css styling from one file then gets more styling from another css file which is loaded after the first styling. Apply all desired styling to the button via your custom css and remove the other.

Comment: Declare the buttons text colors in your htmls head-section, before the buttons. That way your browser knows how to display the buttons, even before it knows where to display them.